# Should we keep [combat]?

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [combat](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combat) currently has 8 questions, which are used for the following:

- 5: *Magic: The Gathering*
- 1: *Munchkin*
- 1: *Dungeon!*
- 1: Recommendation request for games with a certain combat mechanic (closed)

There is no tag wiki for this, and it's not clear how it's intended to be used. It looks as though it's being used for any combat mechanic within board and card games, and that suggests to me that it's too broad.

Should we keep [combat](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combat) or delete it?

Comment: Is there enough of an agreement to move forward on removing the tag?

Comment: @JoeW Definitely. Is the best way to deal with it to just manually delete it, bumping all questions for it to the front page? Or do we have a mod do some magic to remove the tag without bumping the question?

Comment: If we can get it done without bumping all the better but its not a lot of questions and can be done slowly if needed

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This tag doesn't sound like it is one that will have any experts in it as combat is different in many games.

I would recommend removing this tag.

Comment: I've deleted the tag from all questions that have it.